Hugging Face model not loading - serverless api
I tried to test a custom model by using the serverless api on vs code but I keep receiving this Status Code: 503 Response Text:

{"error":"Model merve/gemma-7b-it-8bit is currently loading","estimated_time":373.2806091308594}

I tried to increase the wait time and retry times but it just loops and nothing changes, model still not loading.
